# Kickstarter like stacked image background in homepage

Tags: html, css

I want to imitate the stacked images used in the kickstarter.com. My problem is that the images doesn't overflow in the screen. The arrow points the remaining space to be filled with image.

Here is the image
http://postimage.org/image/9we1jinkz/

HTML:

```
 <div id="projectGrid">
    <div class="project"><a href="thumbLink"><img src="img/p1.png" /></a></div>
    <div class="project"><a href="thumbLink"><img src="img/p2.png" /></a></div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.project {float:left;overflow:hidden;}
 #projectGrid {

background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #222222;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
z-index: 6;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the container wider to incorporate an even number of images?

Comment: could you please to correct your english a bit as I dont understand what you want to achieve? What do you mean your images don't overflow?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an external container to the projectGrid which will take 80% of the total width of the screen then the rest of your content set it on a smaller width. It's quite basic CSS layout. Apparently you copy pasted some of the html and some of the CSS out of kickstarter.com website. I strongly suggest you study how CSS works before trying to achieve complicated layouts like these.
http://tinkerbin.com/fVhY1DHr